# stack in MSYS2 extra include

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am on Windows 10 with MSYS2
In the MINGW64 shell,i try to install the brick package which requires ncurse.h

```
stack install brick
```

I have added the include path in `stack.yaml`
but stack still complains:
Any ideas how to fix this?

```
brick-0.1.0.0: build
Preprocessing library brick-0.1.0.0...
In-place registering brick-0.1.0.0...
setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3.exe: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-7.10.3\bin\ghc-pkg.exe'
exited with an error:
brick-0.1.0.0: Warning: haddock-interfaces: C:\msys64\home\  user\haskell\brick\.stack-work\dist\2672c1f3\doc\html\brick\brick.haddock
doesn't exist or isn't a file
brick-0.1.0.0: Warning: haddock-html: C:\msys64\home\user\haskell\brick\.stack-work\dist\2672c1f3\doc\html\brick doesn't exist or
isn't a directory
brick-0.1.0.0: include-dirs: /usr/include/ncurses is a relative path which
makes no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can make
paths relative to the package database itself by using ${pkgroot}. (use
--force to override)

--  While building package brick-0.1.0.0 using:
      C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\stack\setup-exe-cache\x86_64-windows\setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3.exe --builddir=.stack-work\dist\2672c1f3 build lib:brick exe:brick-exe --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: `brick` depends on `vty` which [does not support windows](https://github.com/coreyoconnor/vty#windows).

Comment: But I'm inside MSYS2, still not enough?

Comment: As I understand it, msys is just native windows, i.e. you can only use windows APIs.

Comment: This is bizzare. So many linux tools way more complicated has been 'ported' on MSYS2, `vty` should be a piece of cake. Anway, this isn't what the error told me though. it says my include dir is a relative path